# What does the shaped charge pickup do?

Tags: unreal-tournament-3

I found this pickup item in *Unreal Tournament 3*, in the Avalanche map (warfare gamemode), called the **Shaped Charge**, but I have no idea how it works. When I pick it up, I can't switch weapons until I place it. What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this website](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Unreal_Tournament_3/Shaped_Charge):

> The shaped charge is a detonation pack generally only found in warfare maps. It is usually used to destroy barricades or trigger special events, such as the avalanche in the avalanche map.

The page also says once picked up you cannot switch weapons until you use it.